# Python tools/libraries to validate a JSON schema

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

Are there any python libraries or tools that check if a JSON schema is valid?

I do not want to validate an instance against a JSON schema, but I would like to check if the JSON schema itself is valid or not. For example, if all the required fields are specified or not, or whether the data types are valid types or not.

I already had a look at `check_schema()` from `jsonschema` library, but this library does not check the aspects that I have mentioned above.

Comment: What happens if you provide `jsonschema.validate` with an invalid JSON schema? Will it raise errors or just silently take it?

Comment: https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/schemas.html#validation

Comment: I dont understand why the question is closed?

Comment: Why is this question closed?

Comment: It is closed because it is asking for a tool or library. This is covered by [help/on-topic] "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: https://json-schema.org/implementations.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a schema validator for validating schemas. There are special schemas called meta-schemas, that validate other "normal" schemas (and themself). For the json schema specification, you can download such meta-schemas from the [specification webpage](https://json-schema.org/specification.html).

There you can download the "Core/Validation Dialect meta-schema". You then can validate any other json schema with

```
$ jsonschema -i your_specific_schema.json meta_schema.json
```

Of cource you can also use it in your python code.

Comment: @Jakob_Stark Can I use the meta_schemas as they are or do I need to extend them according to my use case?

Comment: You can use it as it is. It validates all other correct json schemas (including itself).